# C++, How to read data from file and insert in container: Map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

I have a problem with fill container map with information . I read the information with operator>> but it gives me these errors in my second class CDealer. `no operator ">>" matches these operands` and `binary">>": no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const CStock'(or these is no acceptable conversion)`
I have three classes: CStock, CDealer who have `map<CStock, pair<unsigned, double>> Stock;` and CShop who have `vector<CDealer*> Dealers;` 
I'll be very thankful if someone can help me.

This is my operators << and >> in CStock

```
  ostream &operator << (ostream &toStream, const CStock &S){
        toStream << "Name Stock: " << S.m_strName_stock << " Producer: " << S.m_strProducer <<
            "Date: " << S.Date;

        return toStream;
    }

    istream &operator >> (istream &fromStream, CStock &S)
    {return fromStream >> S.m_strName_stock >> S.m_strProducer >> S.Date;}
```

This is my operators << and >> in CDealer
`

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &toStream, CDealer &D) 
{
    toStream << "Name Dealer: " << D.m_strName_Dealer << " Agent: " << D.m_strAgent <<
        "Address: " << D.m_strAddress;

    map<CStock, pair<unsigned, double>>::const_iterator it = D.Stock.begin();
    while (it != D.Stock.end())
    {
        toStream << it->first <<it->second.first << it->second.second;
    }
    return toStream;
}

istream &operator >> (istream &fromStream, CDealer &D)
{
    map<CStock, pair<unsigned, double>>::iterator it = D.Stock.begin();
    fromStream >> D.m_strName_Dealer >> D.m_strAgent >> D.m_strAddress;

    while (it!= D.Stock.end())
    {fromStream >> it->first >> it->second.first >> it->second.second;}
    return fromStream
}
```

And this is the constructor with parameter: file name and these tho operators <<, >>

```
CShop::CShop(const string &fname)
{
    CDealer c;
    fstream File(fname, ios::in);
    if (File.is_open())
    {
        File >> m_strNameShop;
        File >> m_strCity;

        while (File>>c)
        {   
            Dealers.push_back(new CDealer(c));
        }
        File.close();   

    }

    else
        throw "ERROR! ";
}
ostream &operator << (ostream &toStream, const CShop &S)
{
    toStream << "Name Shop: " << S.m_strNameShop << " City: " << S.m_strCity;

    vector<CDealer* >::const_iterator it = S.Dealers.begin();


    while (it != S.Dealers.end())
    {
        CDealer* dealerPtr = *it++;
        toStream << *dealerPtr<< endl;
    }
    return toStream;
}
    istream &operator >> (istream &fromStream, CShop &D)
    {
        return fromStream >> D.m_strNameShop >> D.m_strCity;

    }
```

And in the end main()

```
#include"CDealer.h"
#include"CShop.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    CShop SS1("data.txt");
    cout << SS1;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out [ask], and provide a [mcve]. As-is, there is a lot of code here - most of which is completely unrelated to your problem. It would help if there was a short program, with the problem directly indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implmentation of `istream &operator >> (istream &fromStream, CDealer &D)`
is poorly thought through.

The objective of the function is to read data from an input stream and flesh out the contents of the `CDealer` object. Normally the `operator<<` and `operator>>` functions work in tandem so that what you write using `operator<<` can be read back using `operator>>`.

From that point of view, even the `operator<<` function needs to revamped.

Here's one implementation that should work as long as there are no spaces in the string objects. If you have space in your string objects, the code needs be changed.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &toStream, CDealer cosnt& D) 
{
   // Write the name of the dealer, without any decorative text.
   // Add a space character to the output so you can read the name back.
   toStream << D.m_strName_Dealer << " ";

   // Do the same for name of the agent and address.
   toStream << D.m_strAgent << " ";
   toStream << D.m_strAddress << " ";

   // Write the number of items in Stock first.
   // This will be necessary when reading the data.
   toStream << D.Stock.size() << " ";

   // Now write the Stock items, which spaces between each field you write.
    map<CStock, pair<unsigned, double>>::const_iterator it = D.Stock.begin();
    while (it != D.Stock.end())
    {
        toStream << it->first << " " << it->second.first << " " << it->second.second << " ";
    }
    return toStream;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &fromStream, CDealer &D)
{
   // Read the name of the dealer.
   fromStream >> D.m_strName_Dealer;

   // Read the name of the agent.
   fromStream >> D.m_strAgent;

   // Read the address.
   fromStream >> D.m_strAddress;

   // Read the number of items.
   size_t num;
   fromStream >> num;

   // Now read the Stock items.
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i )
   {
      // Obtained the types for key, val1, and val2 from
      // the error message posted in a comment by OP.
      CStock key;
      int val1;
      double val2;
      fromStream >> key >> val1 >> valu2;

      // Add the item to Stock.
      D.Stock.insert(std::make_pair(key, std::make_pair(val1, val2)));
   }

    return fromStream
}
```

Comment: Great, but it gives me this mistake:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0304 no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=const CStock, _Ty=std::pair<unsigned int, double>, _Pr=std::less<const CStock>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const CStock, std::pair<unsigned int, double>>>]" matches the argument list

Comment: @Kristiyan, You have to use the right types for `key`, `val1`, and `val2`. It seems type of `key` is `CStock`, type of `val1` is `int` and type of `val2` is `double`.

Comment: @R Sahu Thank you very much! You are great!

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The problem can be reduced to the following case:

```
#include <map>
 
int main(void) {
    std::map<int, int> val;
 
    auto it = val.begin();
    it->first = 10;
}
```

The key values in a `std::map` are `const` (the pair of key and value is defined as `std::pair<const Key, T>`), so for

```
 map<CStock, pair<unsigned, double>>
```

we have a `map` containing `pair`s of

```
std::pair<const CStock, pair<unsigned, double>>
```

which makes `it->first` in

```
fromStream >> it->first >> it->second.first >> it->second.second;
```

a `const CStock` and results in the reported error.

This all makes sense because the `map` is ordered by the key, so if you could change the key whenever you wanted to whatever you wanted the `map` would soon be incoherent.

[Documentation on `std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

## Solution

There is no simple solution. You cannot do this. You must either make the items and then place them in the `map` or use one of the `emplace` family of functions to construct them directly in the `map`. Once they are in the `map` you can change the value, but not the key. You could remove the item, and thus the key, and reinsert with a different key, but why are you doing this in the first place? I recommend a rethink of your logic.